# Why Xamarin can not find AppleSDK?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Xamarin an error:

> "A valid Xcode installation could not be found. If your copy of Xcode
>   is installed to a non-standard prefix, please specify the location in
>   Xamarin Studio's Preferences under 'SDK Locations'."

In the setting can not find AppleSDK.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Re-installing the application might be helpful.
Are you under Windows, Linux or MacOS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you can see where you need to se the location of Xcode.app:

[image: Here it is]